# Rising edge interrupt triggering multiple times on STM32 Nucleo

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, mbed

I am using the STM32 NUCLEO-F401RE microcontroller board.

I have a speaker programmed to change frequency by a set amount when the joystick is pushed up/down. My issue is that sometimes (more often than not) when the joystick is pushed up/down the frequency increases/decreases multiple times, implying that the ISR is executing multiple times. Also, the InterruptIn object is set to trigger on the rising edge however sometimes it also executes on the falling edge (when the joystick is returend to neutral after pushing up/down). Any help for getting over this?

```
void upISR()
{
    if (greenLED.getStatus())
    {
        myTicker.detach();
        frequency+=200;   
        myTicker.attach(callback(&spkr, &Speaker::toggle), 0.5/frequency); 
    }
}
```

'

```
int main()
{
    InterruptIn up(A2);
    InterruptIn down(A3);
    InterruptIn fire(D4);

    up.rise(&upISR);
    down.rise(&downISR);
    fire.rise(&toggleISR);

    redLED.on();

    while (1){}
}
```

Comment: This is a classic problem, read about "Debouncing" (switch debouncing, button debouncing)

Comment: @BenVoigt  A lot of what I have read describes the problem excellently, to then only present some shockingly bad software solutions.  Few deal with switches directly triggering interrupts, with solutions inappropriate for use in an interrupt context. How is the OP supposed to sort the good from the bad advice (or that which may or may not be applicable to this situation)?  Better perhaps to post an answer here and let its quality be gauged by the community - only counting _legal votes_ of course ;-).

Comment: @Clifford: Because while "shockingly bad" is not good for *any* situation, neither does a "good" solution in one situation solve all situations.  I couldn't give a complete answer on the basis of only the information OP has provided in the question... also having some oscilloscope traces and a schematic of the connection between the switch and the MCU would be helpful.

Comment: you generally do not want to interrupt on the switch state changes, that rarely works.  one option is a timer based interrupt and periodically sample the switch and take the value you get and use it. Another is a filter which basically in some form you oversample the switch state and look for X in a row at one level or apply math to it to remove glitches, 15 out of 16 are at the same level, etc.  up down counter that is set in the middle each time you start sampling again if it gets to a threshold there were enough ones or zeros, etc...

Comment: its simple as you have a normal (not pushed) state and a pushed state so you are looking for it to be in the pushed state but not all the glitches, so then you have to decide to I force a normal state or do I have a press and hold feature and if so then how do you define/sample for that...

Comment: buttons are more complicated than interrupts.  you can also apply hardware (analog or digital but thinking analog here) an RC or some other analog low pass filter but that incurs a delay which is probably fine for human manual speed stuff. (the oversampling digitally also incurs a delay, all filtering does).

Comment: Thanks for the help from everyone. @old_timer this program was part of an exercise in interrupts for which we weren't allowed to use polling but otherwise your suggestions all sound good and I'll be noting them down for next time. I commented about how I fixed the code on the answer.

Comment: A better solution still involves interrupts but not based on state changes from the switch input.  To debounce that you still need state change per time information so either sampling a timer in the pin state change interrupt or something like that and the problem there is once the state change has stopped bouncing you dont have any more interrupts to declare hey it has been stable for so many milliseconds, therefore I can call it a button press....

Comment: Be it Cliffords answer or other, think about it with respect to time, a scope really helps if fast enough (and doesnt end up filtering the bounce).  Then ponder the what if my chip can actually interrupt on each of these state changes (in some cases you are under sampling it simply due to how your interrupt system works and time in the interrupt).  Even without a scope you can visualize this.  Once switch is bad enough, two is much worse esp since you want to control one item with two switches.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical switch bounce is a feature of all mechanical switches to a lesser or greater extent.  It is often necessary to implement "debouncing" in software especially if the switch is directly driving an interrupt as in this case.

A quick Google search for software denounce techniques yields some rather poor techniques IMO. I seen it done poorly more times than well unfortunately.

I suggest that in the switch ISR you start (or restart in the event of a "bounce")  a hardware timer for a period of say 20ms or so (longer than the switch bounce time, but shorter than the time you could possibly to genuinely release the switch).  Then in the timer ISR, you test the state of the switch and change the frequency accordingly:

Pseudocode:

```
void upISR()
{
    debounceTimerRestart() ;
}

void downISR()
{
    debounceTimerRestart() ;
}

void debounceTimerISR()
{
    debounceTimerStop() ;

    tDirection dir = getJoystickDir() ;
    swithc( dir )
    {
        case UP :
        {
            increaseFrquency() ;
        }
        break ;

        case DN :
        {
            decreaseFrquency() ;
        }
        break ;
    }
}
```

What this does is trigger a timer interrupt shortly ("debounce time") after the switch *stops* bouncing.  Note the timer is "single-shot" not periodic.

Below I present an enhancement at  @BenVoigt's suggestion (in comments). I am keeping it separate to make it clear it was his work. The above will generally work, but if you have a particularly poor switch the following would resolve issues, and at little cost, so you may as well:

```
void debounceTimerISR()
{
    debounceTimerStop() ;

    static tDirection previous_dir = CENTRE ;
    tDirection dir = getJoystickDir() ;

    // If the state changed...
    if( previous_dir != dir )
    {
        previous_dir = dir ;

        switch( dir )
        {
            case UP :
            {
                increaseFrquency() ;
            }
            break ;

            case DN :
            {
                decreaseFrquency() ;
            }
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple change would provide glitch rejection also, to wit, compare the value from `getJoystickDir()` to the previous value of `getJoystickDir()`, and increase or decrease the frequency only if the stick currently is in the active position and previously was not.

Comment: @BenVoigt possibly, but in most cases unnecessary, but a cost free enhancement nonetheless. If after the timer expires the stick is neither up nor down, nothing happens. Any "positive glitch' with duration less than the debounce time is automatically rejected as it is. It is true that a "negative glitch" where the switch momentarily opens while being held closed would be seen as a transition that your suggestion would solve, and may be necessary with a particularly poor, dirty or worn switch perhaps, but the life of the hardware is perhaps limited by then.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Upon reflection, added your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Clifford thanks a lot for your help and explanations. I implemented debouncing in my code with the use of a flag that is set when any of the ISRs are called, and cleared after a short timer, with the ISRs not being able to execute if the flag is set. Reckon that's an okay way of implementing it?

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the effective suggestion. The joystick is out of the scope of the ISR for this exercise however I'll definitely be remembering your suggestion for next time.

Comment: @mvem_ While your solution would work, it is not noise/glitch immune, and has no real benefits over simply polling on a timer as suggested by P_J. He has a point.  If you wish to discuss your solution you should either post it as an answer here or post a new question, SO is not a discussion forum, and this is not an appropriate use of the comments feature

Answer (score 0):

We clearly believe this is the normal and expected bouncing of the switch.  Mechanically a switch is some piece of metal that when acted on moves that metal from one pole to another, even if they do not resemble a wiper and two poles.  The metal that moves will collide and bounce, the electrical connection will show that.  The bouncing is often slow enough for a processor to get multiple interrupts, although that may be an under-sampling of all the bounces possibly seen electrically.  If you try to look at it on a scope the scope itself may not-intentionally be filtering some of it (but so will your chip).

One way to see the problem is as with anything, research first then write the application later.  This is not a solution but a way to characterize the problem for your system

```
switch_isr ( void )
{
    ...
    some_global_variable <<= 1;
    some_global_variable |= (pin_state_register>>pin_number)&1;
    ...
}

main ( void )
{
...
some_local_variable = 0;
while(1)
{
   if(some_local_variable != some_global_variable)
   {
       some_local_variable = some_global_variable;
       primitive_hex_print(some_local_variable);
   }
}
}
```

No reason to expect to see every state change in the shifted variable, but you should see some and get a feel for the problem.  Another way is to just have a counter increment on every interrupt, print periodically in the foreground and you will see one button press may result in multiple counts. And from the time it takes for the printouts to stop changing roughly in human time the settling time.

Filtering is all about state changes per unit time though and you have to have some flavor of time, be it a loop in the foreground that polls some information set by the interrupt (up/down counters, etc), or state changes relative to a timer/clock.

I do not know what the complete rules are for your assignment, if you can only have an interrupt for each switch and not a timer, or preferably a timer instead, I do not see a clean solution that will actually work.  You would have to filter in the foreground but all that is doing is polling a copy of the pin state collected by the interrupt and is that any different than not using the interrupt?  You cannot use Clifford's answer if you cannot set a timer interrupt, if you could use a timer and an interrupt then you could just periodically sample the switch states with that interrupt or a copy of the pin state collected by the pin state change interrupts and filter in the timer interrupt.  Not the same as Clifford's but in all cases you need state change history relative to time to see when the thing settles.

Without a time reference and states not changing with respect to time (which a pin interrupt cannot show since the state has not changed) you cannot filter out the bounces.  Instead work on your dexterity and how you flick the joystick up and down.

Comment: Please take care with your spellings here, especially words containing apostrophes. Here are some correct spellings, plus the number of mispellings in your post history: don't (765), doesn't (488), won't (217), can't (306). There is some tolerance here for people who don't have English as a first language, but stylistic and deliberate misspelling works against the aims of the site. Do you have a spell-checker available in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Simple do not use EXTI for mechanical yousticks and buttons.

Use regular interrupt (for example systick) to poll the status of the pins.