# Disable interrupt to let freeRTOS run on stm32

Tags: embedded, stm32, interrupt, freertos, stm32f4discovery

I'm working a project where I am getting digital samples continuously through DMA on STM32f4. DMA generates a complete callback interrupt after every sample where I do some DSP. My plan is to allow freeRTOS to work on other tasks while DMA is waiting on the callback. However, DMA is generating callback too frequently, not allowing freeRTOS to run. I want to make it so that after every DMA complete callback, freeRTOS tasks is allowed to run for 6ms. I thought of calling `__disable_irq()` from complete callback and `__enable_irq()` from one of the tasks but that would not guarantee 6ms also I have a high priority button interrupt. I also tried disabling just DMA interrupt calling `__set_BASEPRI(priority<<(8-__NVIC_PRIO_BITS))` then starting a timer for 6ms. On timer period elapsed callback in call `__set_BASEPRI(0)` to enable DMA interrupt. But for some reason this did not allow freeRTOS to run at all. It goes back and forth between DMA complete callback and Timer period elapsed callback.

I am new to embedded programming so any comment on this will help. Thank You.

Comment: What is your sample rate?

Comment: It is a bit of an X-Y problem.  You are asking about how to implement what you think is a solution, when you should probably step back and ask more holistically how to achieve your task scheduling and DSP deadlines on the hardware you have.  It is not clear form your description perhaps, but I would say that you are not using the RTOS appropriately. Your apparent RTOS/DSP divide is a false one.  In an RTOS you should do almost everything in tasks and almost nothing in interrupts.  Any significant processing in an interrupt will compromise the RTOS's ability to respond deterministically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not think of the DSP process being separate from the RTOS tasks, do the DSP *in* an RTOS task - the signal processing is the most time critical aspect of your system, you have to process the data as fast as it arrives with no loss.

If the DSP is being done in an interrupt context and starving your tasks, then clearly you are doing too much work in the interrupt context, and have too high an interrupt rate.  You need to fix your design for something more schedulable.

If your DMA transfers are single samples, you will get one interrupt per sample - the ADC will do that on its own; so using DMA in that manner offers no advantage over direct ADC interrupt processing.

Instead you should use block processing, so you DMA a block of say 80 samples samples cyclically, for which you get a half-transfer interrupt at 40 samples, and full-transfer interrupt at 80 samples. So for each interrupt you might then trigger a task-event or semaphore to defer the DSP processing to a *high-priority* RTOS task.  This achieves two things;

1. For the entirety of the *n* sample block acquisition time, the RTOS is free to:

- be performing the DSP processing for the previous block,
- use any remaining time to process the lower priority tasks.

2. Any interrupt overhead spent context switching etc. is reduced by 1/*n*, allowing more time performing core signal processing and background tasks.

Apart form reducing the number of interrupts and software overhead, the signal processing algorithms themselves can be optimised more readily when performing block-processing.

A variation on the above is rather then triggering a task event or semaphore from the DMA interrupt handler, you could place the new sample block in a message queue, which will then provide some buffering.  This is useful if the DSP processing might be less deterministic, so cannot *always* guarantee to complete processing of one block before the next is ready.  However overall it remains necessary that on average you complete block processing in the time it takes to acquire a block, with time to spare for other tasks.

If your lower priority tasks are still starved, then the clear indication is that your DSP process is simply too much for your processor.  There may be scope for optimisation, but that would be a different question.

Using the suggested block-processing strategy I have in the past migrated an application from a TI C2000 DSP running at 200MHz and 98% CPU load, to a 72MHz STM32F1xx at 60% CPU load.  The performance improvement is potentially very significant if you get it right.

With respect to your "high-priority" button interrupt, I would question your priority assignment.  Buttons are operated manually with human response and perception times measured in 10's or even 100's of milliseconds.  That is hardly your time critical task, whereas missing an ADC sample of a few *microseconds* would cause your signal processing to go seriously awry.

You may be making the mistake of confusing "high-priority" with "important".  In the context or a real-time system, they are not the same thing.  You could simply poll the button in a *low-priority* task, or if you use an interrupt, the interrupt should do no more than signal a task (or more realistically trigger a de-bounce timer) (see [Rising edge interrupt triggering multiple times on STM32 Nucleo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775785/rising-edge-interrupt-triggering-multiple-times-on-stm32-nucleo/64776403#64776403) for example).